# code for image run in arraylist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

i do array list with images thet i want them to run with 2 buttons thet go next pic and beck pic i dont know the code for this i thx all for the time you spend for help.

```
    ackage com.example.hanansanag.mytourneyccreator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ssh on 25/12/2016.
 */

public class Players extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected Button btnNext, btnBack;
    protected String fname;
    protected String Lname;
    protected String team;
    protected ImageView iv;
    protected ArrayList array_image;
    int i = 1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_pic);
        ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        array_image.add(R.drawable.bacelona);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.athlethiko);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.arsenak);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.chelsea);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.dortmond);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.city);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.bayernunchen);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.intermilan);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.psj);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.realmadrid);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.leverpool);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.milan);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.juventus);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.ashkelon);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.macabiheifa);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.macabitelaviv);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.beitaryeroshlaim);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.apoelbersheva);


        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextPic);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeckPic);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (i <= 0 || i >= array_image.length) {
            return;
        }

        if (btnNext == v) {
            iv.setImageResource(array_image.get(i++));

        } else if (btnBack == v) {
            iv.setBackgroundResource(array_image.get(i--));

        }

    }
}
```

**what can i do here in this line of code thet the pic will move : **

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (i <= 0 || i >= array_image.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (btnNext == v) {
        iv.setImageResource(array_image.get(i++));

    } else if (btnBack == v) {
        iv.setBackgroundResource(array_image.get(i--));

    }

}
```

**this is the xml;**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/teamimage">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:text="Fname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/Lname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Fname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnBeckPic"
        android:background="@drawable/btnbeck"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Lname"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/btnnext"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNextPic"

        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnBeckPic"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so what is the problem of your code ? P.S: instead of `ibtnNext == v` and `btnBack == v` check id of those like `if(v.getId() == R.id....)`.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan the problem thet the code in onclick no work he say error for the code thet in the position i put "i" he dont get it and in the

Comment: in this code : iv.setImageResource(array_image.get(i++)); he say error i think there is somthink like advance array pic somthing like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int currentImage = 0;
String[] strArr = new String[array_image.size()];
strArr = array_image.toArray(stockArr);

       @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (btnNext == v) {

           currentImage++;
                currentImage = currentImage % strArr .length;

                iv.setImageResource(strArr .length[currentImage]);

        } else if (btnBack == v) {
            currentImage--;
                currentImage = (currentImage + strArr .length) % strArr .length;

                iv.setImageResource(strArr[currentImage]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: first of all ty verry much for your help and time!

Comment: sry i post agine he dont let me to edit becuz im new i have problem he dont get the array_image.length i dont know way "lengh" in red meybe the problem is thet i put in start "protected ArrayList array_image;" meybe i need to get it in some ather code? i dont know way its in red

Comment: you can use array_image.size();

Comment: thx its help but naw lol the problem is in :    iv.setImageResource(array_image[currentImage]);  the " arrat_image in red and he say : "array type expected : found java.util.list<java.util.list<java.lang.integer>>

Comment: i add pic for you to see better : https://postimg.org/image/5y6myzifr/                        and : https://postimg.org/image/jye779cgx/                                                                 and: https://postimg.org/image/7z2tyo3a7/

Comment: Try updated above code written by me.I have corrected long back you are still using old one

Comment: still same problem like the pic i upload plz look the images i upload meybe you ill understand the problem beeter

Comment: Got it please check my next answer

Comment: lol you the boss naw i have problem with the stockarr he put it in red error look the image if i put it right plz : aand ty im student so all of this new for me : https://postimg.org/image/aia2s65hf/ and this : https://postimg.org/image/x8u0m1a4x/

Comment: Put below line inside onClick method

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/6hx6puw5r/ still same bro :( plz help i so want to continue my softwer engenire project :(